# "Hardware Error" popping up in dmesg

Tags: hardware, dmesg

I am sporadically (twice in over a month) seeing worrying errors like:

```
[757706.327447] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[757706.327450] [Hardware Error]: Corrected error, no action required.
[757706.327453] [Hardware Error]: CPU:1 (19:21:0) MC20_STATUS[-|CE|MiscV|-|-|-|-|-|-]: 0x8948000000282504
[757706.327457] [Hardware Error]: IPID: 0x0000000000000000
[757706.327459] [Hardware Error]: Bank 20 is reserved.
[757706.327459] [Hardware Error]: cache level: RESV, tx: DATA
```

I also see a bunch of (perhaps unrelated):

```
[725795.673933] audit: type=1400 audit(1664229606.644:1910): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1534043 comm="cupsd" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
[725795.733042] audit: type=1400 audit(1664229606.700:1911): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" name="/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6" pid=1534044 comm="cups-browsed" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

Machine is a self-built server based on "AMD Ryzen 9 5950X 16-Core Processor" with "MemTotal: 32797136 kB" (further details available, if needed) and sporting.

```
mcon@ikea:~$ uname -a
Linux ikea 5.19.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 5.19.6-1 (2022-09-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What should I check?

Answer (score 1):

> `mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged`

mce, or [Machine-check exception](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Machine-check_exception), is an error generated by the CPU when the CPU detects that a hardware error or failure has occurred.

Machine check exceptions (MCEs) can occur for a variety of reasons ranging from undesired or out-of-spec voltages from the power supply, from cosmic radiation flipping bits in memory DIMMs or the CPU, or from other miscellaneous faults, including faulty software triggering hardware errors.

> `[Hardware Error]: Corrected error, no action required.`

apparently it's not that fatal and can be fixed automatically by the CPU/kernel; but there [are](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/system-auto-rebooted-mce-hardware-error-in-dmesg-related-to-cpu/89580) also [few](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206903#c78) other [cases](https://remy.org.uk/tech.php?tech=1657321200) of 5th generation Ryzen [doing](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/nsqz2l/amd_ryzen_9_5900x_mce_hardware_error/) the same, so I'd advise a CPU check for now, e.g. running MPrime for a few hours and see if anything comes up.

To see more details about the hardware error logged, you can use `rasdaemon` as suggested, should be available in Debian repository, or you can try some other MCE decoding tools such as [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-check_exception#Decoding_MCEs).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately trying to run MPrime results in a "Killed" message after a few seconds (and process pointed by `mprime.pid` is actually gone). Any hint?

Comment: When `Killed` message shows, is there any OOM message in your syslog?

Comment: Yes, I found that, but I didn't really understand discussion about it on the internet.

Comment: when `Killed` message shows, try running `tail -n 100 /var/log/syslog` and see if there's any entry about `mprime` got OOM'd. If so, try configuring the benchmark to stress CPU only.